# Why are the directions of torques different with 2 people on each end of the seesaw?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

In this picture, the book says the father has a positive(+) torque with direction coming outside the paper, and the daughter has a negative(-) torque with direction ggoing inside the paper.
I knew torque's sign was determined by the direction of rotation. Clockwise - negative, Counter-clockwise - positive.

The thing is, the father and the daughter on the seesaw are moving both counter-clockwise. So aren't both supposed to have a positive torque value?

[image: father on left, daughter on right side of a seesaw]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction of torque is determined by the direction of the acting *force* (and the direction of the corresponding lever arm), not the direction of rotation. Since the father's and daughter's weights are tending to move the see-saw in opposite directions, their torques are also in opposite directions.

Are you perhaps confusing torque with the similar concept of angular momentum, which *does* depend on the direction of rotation ?